# Documentation for gnomekeyring Python lib

Tags: python, gnome

Is there a documentation for Python 'gnomekeyring' lib somewhere in the Web?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the [reference for the C library](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gnome-keyring/stable/) which the Python package uses. Most function names are identical (except for the "gnome_keyring_" prefix). The [Bending Gnome Keyring with Python](http://blogs.codecommunity.org/mindbending/bending-gnome-keyring-with-python-part-1/) blog series should give you a good start as well.

And as the [keyring](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring) package was already mentioned: If I remember correctly, that package supports gnome-keyring as a backend, so you can look at its source code to find out how to use gnome-keyring.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the blog -- that'll do the job!

Comment: ugh. I'm maintainer of the keyring package and I'm searching for an answer to this question so keyring can more robustly handle the exceptions that come out of gnomekeyring. I'd love some docs or even just the source code.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs Any updates on this question? Does anyone have source code of the gnomekeyring package or documentation?

Comment: @user128063 `keyring` has dropped support defacto support for Gnomekeyring, instead relying on [SecretStorage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SecretStorage). Perhaps that's the best approach for everyone?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently not. But this one is documented, maybe that's an option?

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring

If not, maybe you can figure out how to use gnomekeyring from reading the source of keyring. :)

Comment: Yep, I've seen this one, but I'm kind of bound to the gnomekeyring lib. Inspecting the source is an option, but it's always easier to read docs (if they exist) :)

Comment: Given that `keyring` is compatible not only with Gnome-Keyring but also a multitude of other platforms (KDE, and even Windows), and has such a nice API, I wonder why anyone would use Gnome-Keyring directly when programming in Python

Comment: Unless, of course, you *are* a `keyring` maintainer. If so, good luck @JasonR.Coombs (and nice job, btw! I'm a fan!)